# How to automatically login with root user in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, root, autologin

I want to enable auto-logon with root user for some specific purpose.  It's so boring that every time I power on my PC to study, I have to input user and password.

Comment: This is Fedora 17

Comment: On the issue of running as root vs. a regular user, see [Concern about logging in as root overrated?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/concern-about-logging-in-as-root-overrated)

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to edit this file (`/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`) and add the following line:

```
autologin-user = root
```

Comment: Please note, **this is a gigantic hole in the security of your system!**

Comment: @Braiam - in general yes. It kind of goes without saying that you wouldn't do this on a server. But if it's a desktop system running Fedora and it's for personal use then user's can do as they wish.

Comment: My comment wasn't for you, but for anyone who read the answer ;). But I can't mention @readers.

Comment: @Braiam - I figured, I was just qualifying your comment.

Comment: Thank you, slm. And thank for your recommend, Braiam, i'm system administration and your caution is the fisst lesson :)

Comment: This does not work for me. I tried adding the line in the sections `[Seat:*]` and/or `[LightDM]`, but on Debian Buster it does not do anything. How could I debug this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to still use a regular user, but to configure **sudo** without password. Anytime you need to do a root command, you can just do:

```
# sudo command
```

If you want to have a terminal opened with sudo shell, do

```
# sudo bash
```

Note this is still giantic hole in the security of your system :-) As root do:

```
# visudo
```

and add this line:

```
yourusername ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

If you like this solution, you can maybe slightly increase the security by configuring long timeout for passwords. So you only will be asked one an hour/day or week.