# What is the security advantage of running as non-root user?

Tags: root

I have heard the advice to not work as root user. One convention is to create a server@server user (instead of root@server) and do all the rest administrative tasks as that user.

What is the advantage of logging in as a non-root superuser, compared to root, from the security point of view?

Comment: There is no "non-root superuser" except as a misnomer on the internets, I believe.  Maybe you should include a link to sources explaining this convention.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' is there any reason you can't change the name of the user who has the UID `0`? I think you can have a non-root root quite simply by editing `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: You can create additional accounts with the UID 0. I believe we've discussed this somewhere before here.

Comment: @terdon True. And if you change your name, you will no longer be terdon. However, this seems a frivolous point since the OP refers to a "non-root superuser, compared to root". If this "non-root superuser" is root with the name changed, **obviously they are exactly the same.**  However, if you google "non-root superuser", you'll see the cruft I'm referring to, which IMO has confused the OP.  But I've been wrong before, which is why I asked for a clarification. *If this is a misnomer, we should not let it be propagated further here.*  It needs to be explained properly, or corrected as a mistake.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' indeed, my understanding was that the OP is referring to the idea of making the super user's user name not root to protect from brute force attacks on root's password.

Comment: @slm Unless there is a mechanism by which those "superusers" can have their privileges delimited in a way that "root" cannot, it's still a red herring issue.  As in, irrelevant.  There is no sensible question.

Comment: @terdon That would be a fair question but you have to read a lot in to get that -- if this is the case, the question is textbook *unclear*, since it could be interpreted a bunch of ways.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' - I wasn't commenting on the Q, only that there was a prior discussion on UID 0 8-). I voted to to close this as unclear.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1052/135943

Answer (score 4):

It's not just a security issue. It's a "I'm less likely to destroy my system by accident by typing something stupid" issue. As goldilocks said, there is no such thing as a "non-root superuser". Common sense dictates that you should run with as few privileges as possible. That is all.

Comment: "Common sense" is also referred to as "least privilege" in security discussions.

Answer (score 2):

The advantages of a "non root, unlimited superuser" are essentially nil (unless you count the protection against brute force attacks - many more attempts will be done against `root` than against `server`).

The advantages appear as soon as you *delegate* functions and create a set of limited superusers, or superuser commands through the `sudo` mechanism, because this way you can run those administrative tasks -- *and only those*. A successful break-in in the "webserver admin" personality will then be able to restart a webserver or rotate logs, but not install administrative software, run privileged commands, lower the firewall shields.

Of course this assumes that you have defense in depth - for example the "create new file for website" function of `sudo` will **check** that the new file requested is not a special file, is not executable, and is in a valid webroot. The `sudo gcc` command will have to verify that the issuer is not overwriting a system binary with a different file, and so on. If by just typing `sudo su` an ordinary user can get superuser privileges, then the system might actually be **less** secure than if it only had a root user (think of a fire-and-forget "joe" account with guessable password: in such a case, it would supply a ready backdoor to rootdom).

Comment: I'm still curious as to what a "limited superuser" would be.  I can't find any explanation of this anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better described as a "power user". Someone who has the same rights as the superuser in *some* fields, but not all. It was traditionally done by carefully SUID'ing key binaries, or supplying suid wrappers, before `sudo` came by.

Comment: Yes, I'll agree that is a *much* better and less confusing term.  "Administrative user" is probably better still. Someone who can leap tall buildings in a single bound but is not faster than a speeding bullet or more powerful than a locomotive *is not* Superman.  It is just someone with a superman-like ability. ;)