# Installing software as root without creating any users

Tags: linux, gentoo

Just installed Gentoo and now I want to install Xorg. Xorg creates an `.xinitrc` in the user folder where you can run a desktop environment or a window manager from. What happens when no users are created and you install Xorg as root?

Where will `.xinitrc` be?

How about other applications' config files? Will they be created if I install them as root? If so, where?

Answer (score 1):

The root user has a home directory, just like any other user.  On many Unix system, it's `/root`, although I've never used Gentoo Linux (it would be the directory that `cd` with no arguments takes you to, when running it as root).  Configuration files that are automatically created for the use by the root user specifically would be created therein.

I would strongly suggest that you *don't* use the root account for anything other than the occasional administrative task though.  The root user should never have to be customised or be set up with a desktop environment.  There is no overhead to setting up a non-privileged user that you occasionally use `sudo` with, for example.

Related:

- [Concern about logging in as root overrated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/concern-about-logging-in-as-root-overrated)
- [Non root Xorg](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Non_root_Xorg) (Gentoo Linux documentation link)