# How to clean /tmp?

Tags: ubuntu, tmp

1. In general, how can we clean `/tmp` for freeing up the space taken by
   non-needed files?

   Note that I once made a mistake by deleting everything under `/tmp`, and then after rebooting, my Ubuntu was broken. I guess it broke the OS by deleting some system or programs' temporary files created in `/tmp` and still in use. So now I ask what is some safe way to remove nonneeded files created by some programs? (I can recognize unneeded files created directly by myself, such as a file copied by me into `/tmp`, but not those not created directly by me even though `ls` may show my name as the creater).
2. In particular, I ran a program called `pdfbeads`, it created some
   very big file(s) in `/tmp` (I suspect the file is `/tmp/magick-HMwXHfQo` which is 1.2GB),and then my `/` partition for`/tmp` ran
   out of space and the program aborted.

   Now my `/`  partition is still filled up. How can I clean `/tmp` for
   freeing up the space taken by non-needed files?

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Rebooting the machine should take care of stopping the services and then restart them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, solution without rebooting?

Comment: From a quick glance most people look to see how long the files have been in the directory & delete things that haven't been used in 4 days now if you are using this on a server that is constantly running certain programs which use the `/tmp` directory this *could* cause problems. [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11235/is-it-safe-to-rm-rf-tmp) has some explanation, but **tmpreaper**looks like it has a better way of checking to see if any file is being used at the time. [Link](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tmpreaper-cleans-up-files-in-directories-based-on-their-age.html) here

Comment: `/tmp/magick-*` are usually temporary files created by IM (`imagemagick`). If IM exits with error those files will not be automatically removed so you'll have to remove them manually. Other than that, see the question linked by @NoTime.

Comment: If `/tmp` is a tmpfs mount, turn on the atime mount option, and delete files with an atime more than 24 hours ago.

Comment: @Patrick: how can I know if /tmp is a tmpfs mount? If yes, how to turn on the atime mount option? What if no?

Comment: @Tim `grep " /tmp " /proc/mounts`

Comment: @Tim - if `/tmp` *is* a tmpfs - and it almost definitely is - then you are probably barking up the wrong tree, im sorry to say - tmpfs is ephemeral - a ramdisk. you might like to know that you can increase the mounted size if needed with `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o remount,size=SIZE /tmp` if necessary - i usually use percent - as a percentage of available RAM - but you can do specific byte counts as well.

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting the system or restarting the failed services should solve the problem. There is probably no way to "repair" a running process which is missing its tmp file.

If you reboot the system often then you may just delete all (old) files in `/tmp` on boot. Otherwise you may use tools like `tmpreaper`.